# The dependent risk model and maximum surplus befor ruin

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

It is well known that the compound Poisson risk model R(t) is given by
$$
R\left(t\right)=u+ct-\sum^{N\left(t\right)}_{i=1}{X_i}=u+ct-S\left(t\right),\ \ \ t\geq{0}
$$
where $u\geq 0$ is the initial surplus, $c$ represents the insurer’s premium income per unit time.

Let ${X_1, X_2, \ldots}$ be independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) positive random variables representing the successive individual claim amounts. These random variables, identically
distributed as the canonical r.v. $X$, are assumed to have common cumulative distribution function
(c.d.f.) $F(x), x \geq 0, \tilde{F}(x) = 1 − F(x)$, with probability density function (p.d.f.) $f (x) = F'(x)$.

The ordinary renewal process ${N(t); t \geq 0}$ denotes the number of claims up to time t and is defined as
$$ N(t) = \sup{(n : W_1 + W_2 + · · · +W_n \leq t)}$$
where the i.i.d. inter-claim times ${W_1, W_2, \ldots}$, identically distributed as the canonical
r.v. $W$ , have common c.d.f. $K(t) = 1 − e^{−\lambda t}, t ≥ 0$, p.d.f. $k(t) = \lambda e^{−\lambda t}, t \geq 0$

The distribution of the maximum surplus before ruin:

For $ b > 0, u \geq 0$, define
$$
G\left(u,b\right)=P\left(\sup_{0\le t\le T}R\left(t\right)<b,\ T<\infty |R\left(0\right)=u\right)
$$
which is the probability of the event that the maximum surplus before ruin is less than $b$ starting
from initial surplus $u$, and $T = \inf{ (t ≥ 0 : R(t) < 0)}$ is the time of ruin of risk model.

By conditioning on the time and the amount of the first claim, we derive that
$$
G\left(u,b\right)=\int^{(b-u)/c}_0{\int^{u+ct}_0{G\left(u+ct-x,b\right)}f_{X,W}\left(x,t\right)dx}dt\\
 +\int^{(b-u)/c}_0{\int^{\infty }_{u+ct}{f_{X,W}\left(x,t\right)dx}dt}
$$

My question is the last equation come from where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in this risk model you are collecting a continuous of income, so your surplus is keep increasing when there is no claim. Before the first claim happen, the surplus at time $t$ is $u + ct$.

If you require the maximum surplus never exceed $b$, then you essentially require the first claim must be early enough such that the surplus will not exceed $b$, so at the time when the first claim happen, we have the surplus $u + cW_1$ and we require

$$ u + cW_1 < b \iff W_1 < \frac {b - u} {c} $$

So this explain the outer integral limits.

Now we consider the claim size $X$. If it exceed $u + cW_1$, then ruin occur immediately, therefore under this condition, the conditional probability is 1, and it form the second integral in the RHS (where $g = 1$).

Otherwise, the ruin is not happen yet and the immediate surplus after claim is $u + cW_1 - X_1$. By the markov property, it is just like we start over again with the new initial surplus $u + cW_1 - X_1$. And this is just the first integral in the RHS.

The most important thing is you know the law of total probability.